# Getting texts between two words in a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

for brevity sake, I have a text file (in windows) that looks like this:

```
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah 2016
START-OF-FILE
ABC
ABCDE Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
END-OF-FILE
Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah
```

I only want the text between START-OF-FILE and END-OF-FILE

```
ABC
ABCDE Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
```

I tried using Findstr, but not working too well.  Can someone help?

here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set quote=

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (infile.txt) do (
  set str=%%a
  set str=!str:"=:!

  if not "!str!"=="!str::=!" (
    if defined quote (
      set quote=
      for %%b in (^"%%a) do set str=%%~b
      if not "!str!"==START-OF-FILE if not "!str: =!"==END-OF-FILE echo !str! >> outfile.txt
    ) else (
      set quote=1
      for %%b in (%%a^") do set str=%%~b
    )
  )

  if defined quote (
    if not "!str!"==START-OF-FILE if not "!str: =!"==END-OF-FILE echo !str! >> outfile.txt
  )
)
```

and this is the result:

```
2016" 
START-OF-FILE 
ABC
ABCDE Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah
Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah Blah
END-OF-FILE
Blah Blah Blah
```

I need the 2016" ,START-OF-FILE ,END-OF-FILE and line after END-OF-FILE (Blah Blah Blah) to not be included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "skip="
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "START-OF-FILE END-OF-FILE" input.txt') do (
   if not defined skip (
      set "skip=%%a"
   ) else (
      set /A "lines=%%a-skip-1"
   )
)
(for /F "skip=%skip% delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   echo %%a
   set /A lines-=1
   if !lines! equ 0 goto break
)) > output.txt
:break
```

Comment: This works!  Which one is more performant?  yours or Magoo?  or are they just two different ways to get the same job done?

Comment: Well, Magoo's code execute three `if`'s by each input line, but my code execute just one `if` per line and one `findstr` command... You may do a timing test just to be sure; I would like to see the result.

Comment: yours takes just half a second longer...but the size is about 2kb smaller.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q36416492.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "output="
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF "%%a"=="END-OF-FILE" SET "output="
 IF DEFINED output ECHO(%%a
 IF "%%a"=="START-OF-FILE" SET "output=Y"
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q36416492.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Uses the fact that `if defined` interprets the run-time value of the variable.

Read each line of the file, set `output` to a value if the ON-trigger string is matched and clear it of the OFF-trigger string is matched. Only regurgitate the line if the flag `output` is defined.

Comment: The sample from Aacini works also.  Which one is more performant?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String[] lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("myfile.txt"));
```

to get all the lines of the file as an array. From there it is simple to loop through them and find the ones you want.

```
String result = "";
boolean withinBounds = false;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
 if (lines[i].equals("START-OF-FILE")) {
  withinBounds = true;
 }
 if (lines[i].equals("END-OF-FILE")) {
  withinBounds = false;
 }
 if (withinBounds) {
  //do whatever you want to do with the lines between your tags here
  result = result + lines[i] + "\n";
 }
}
```

Note this is untested, but the general concept should definitely work for you. Note it also assumes your tags will be on a line by themselves.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I was hoping to do it within a bat file

Comment: ah no problem. i don't think your original code / tags made that clear

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows Powershell

This will be a two step process if you know your start and end points.  First line cuts off the top, the second line cuts off the bottom part.

**get-content** *file.txt* **| select -last** *n* **>** *output.txt*

**get-content** *output.txt* **| select -first** *n* **>** *output2.txt*

It will require this additional step twice if you don't know where your start and end points are...

**type** *file.txt* **| select-string -pattern** *"START_OF_FILE"* **| Select-Object LineNumber**

**type** *file.txt* **| select-string -pattern** *"END_OF_FILE"* **| Select-Object LineNumber**

Comment: How this code know what are the line numbers of `START-OF-FILE` and `END-OF-FILE` marks? (the OP did _not_ asked for a PoSh solution)...

Comment: User wanted it in a .bat file.  So perhaps they were looking for a scripting solution.  It's not clear.  Added the additional steps in case user wants this scripting solution.